# Consulta com caracteres especiais em uma ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, regex, uwp

Criei um método de pesquisa que recebe um texto, e pesquisa esse texto em uma `ObservableCollection` previamente preenchida.

```
    private void btn_Pesquisar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<object> temp = null;

        string oTexto_Pesquisa = txt_Pesquisa.Text.ToLower();
        Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
        oTexto_Pesquisa = rgx.Replace(oTexto_Pesquisa, "");


        /*Procurando Marcas*/
        if (WhereToSearch.Equals("Marcas"))
        {
            temp = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            foreach (Marcas marcas in obs_Marcas)
            {
                if (marcas.Nome.ToLower().Contains(oTexto_Pesquisa) || marcas.Descricao == null ? true : marcas.Descricao.ToLower().Contains(oTexto_Pesquisa))
                {
                    temp.Add(new Marcas
                    {
                        Nome = marcas.Nome,
                        Imagem = marcas.Imagem,
                        Descricao = marcas.Descricao
                    });
                }
            }
            Lista_Marcas.ItemsSource = temp;
        }
```

Ao pesquisar, é retornado os registros dentro dessa `ObservableCollection`.
Mas Há um problema com o `regex`;
Por exemplo, ao pesquisar "as" é retornado o registro "UTAS". Mas ao pesquisar "as-", era esperado retornar o registro "AS-Val" mas não é retornado nenhum registro e não dá nenhum erro. 
Como resolver essa pesquisa?

Comment: Olá @Marceloawq. Seria interessante você complementar sua pergunta postando algumas descrições de produtos da sua lista `obs_Marcas`, apontando inclusive quais os itens que deveriam porém não estão sendo listados.

Comment: @JônatasHudler, editei a pergunta

Comment: @Marceloawq por favor coloque um exemplo de entrada e o que pretende que a regex retorne

Comment: Não posso reproduzi-lo -> http://rextester.com/HIRT9019